# How to add two apps in one app according to iOS version?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

I have an app written in Swift with UIKit which has minimum development target iOS 9. Now I rewrote that app with SwiftUI which supports from iOS 13. I want to use old app for iOS 9.0 - 12.4, new app for iOS 13 and later. How can I do this in one app, with same bundle identifier ? Or any other options to do ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I THINK - if you already upload the first app to the App Store, there is no problem to upload second app as usual. user will download the correct version according to their device. but if you did not upload the first version already, I THINK you can't. you will have to upload 2 different apps.

Comment: @user1105951 thanks, I already uploaded first app. How can I do the logic in one workspace, if user device has iOS 9-12, user must download old app ( or first app, with UIKit); else if has iOS 13 and later, download the second, with SwiftUI ?

Comment: As already mentioned in the answer, you're pretty forced to fork *at least* something. It can be the entire app, or just the UI (provided you moved your model completely away from the UI and can maintain that code centrally). Probably the best thing you can do is (1) clean up and archive your code for the legacy app, (2) take this as an "opportunity" to embrace various changes in iOS & iPadOS 13,  (3) communicate to your users - via a small update? - the worth of (4) purchasing your new updated app that will support the latest things....

Comment: Let them know that the legacy app *will* work with *all* versions of iOS but that new features, such as multiple windows, using three cameras, light/dark mode, etc. are only being supported in your new version.

Answer (score 2):

If you upload your updated app to App Store Connect with the same bundle identifier, it will work but then your users will only be able to update the app if they're running iOS 13.
Since SwiftUI is not backward compatible, any app binary containing SwiftUI code will only run on iOS 13 or later.
So if you want to provide a UIKit version that still gets updates of your app to users running older versions of iOS, you need to create a new app with a separate bundle identifier

Comment: On a personal note, I think you're going to have a hard time maintaining two versions of the same app at the same time. Of course having a framework target that contains all the logic would work, but every time you update your UI in one app, you'd have to do the same in the other one so you're doing twice the work